# How to set Javascript cookie in all the pages / globally?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm having a huge problem with my code, I am trying to check if a cookie exists, and if it does exist, i dont want it to do anything.

Its working fine on page1, but when i navigate to page2 it overrides the cookie, instead of doing nothing (the pages is from the same website)

Heres my script

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();

    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);

    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());

    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);

        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

var omgpost = getCookie("omgpost");

if (omgpost == null || omgpost == "") {
    setCookie("omgpost", "1", 1);
} else {
    alert('cookie installed already');
}
```

This is working fine, when I don't have the cookie installed and entering this site, I'm adding the cookie, and I'm getting the confirmation message each time I refresh the page1.

But when navigating to page2 its recreating the cookie??? I don't want that! I want the cookie to be there, and can't be changed, only when it has expired, how can I do that?

Answer (score 30):

Set Cookie Path using `path=/`

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null)
                                 ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString())
                                + "; path=/";
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Comment: Sad, that's not a problem. :)

Comment: @MaryellenCandeew: You can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it.  That gives the author some rep.