# Contact Form 7 - Set Cookie on submission

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, cookies

So I need a way to grab the values of the fields from a form that uses contact form 7 plugin, using the Additional Settings box on the admin page.
Some way to set a cookie with the field values would be great.

The form:

```
<label>Please type your question</label>
<fieldset class="question">
  [textarea your-message id:questionmessage]
</fieldset>
<label>Name</label>
<fieldset class="name">
  [text* your-name id:questionname]
</fieldset>
<label>Email</label>
<fieldset class="email">
  [email* your-email id:questionemail]
</fieldset>

<label>[Submit button]</label>
<fieldset class="submit">
  [submit "Send"]
</fieldset>
```

Additional Settings, that works so far:

```
on_sent_ok: "location.replace('page2');"
```

I've tried:

```
on_sent_ok: "setcookie('form-email',1,strtotime('+30 days'),COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN,false, false);setcookie('form-name',1,strtotime('+30 days'),COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN,false, false);location.replace('page2');"
```

this still sends the email correctly, but does not redirect to page2 (I know this should just set the cookie values to 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've called in the additional settings box in the admin area.

```
on_sent_ok: "setCookiesAndRedirect("http://www.redirecthere.com");"
```

Then in the form area I've added some javascript to handle the form field values/cookie stuff. This probably isn't great but it works.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  window.onload = function() {
    var namefield = document.getElementById("formfullname");
    var emailfield = document.getElementById("formemail");
    var firstnamefield = document.getElementById("formfirstname");
    var surnamefield = document.getElementById("formsurname");
    var namecookie = getCookie("form-fullname");
    var emailcookie = getCookie("form-email");
    var firstnamecookie = getCookie("form-firstname");
    var surnamecookie = getCookie("form-surname");
    if (namecookie != "" && namefield != null) {
      namefield.value = namecookie;
    }
    if (emailcookie != "" && emailfield != null) {
      emailfield.value = emailcookie;
    }
    if (firstnamecookie != "" && firstnamefield != null) {
      firstnamefield.value = firstnamecookie;
    }
    if (surnamecookie != "" && surnamefield != null) {
      surnamefield.value = surnamecookie;
    }
  } //end load function

function setCookiesAndRedirect(url) {
    var namefield = document.getElementById("formfullname");
    var emailfield = document.getElementById("formemail");
    var firstnamefield = document.getElementById("formfirstname");
    var surnamefield = document.getElementById("formsurname");
    if (namefield != null)
      setCookie("form-fullname", namefield.value, 30);
    if (emailfield != null)
      setCookie("form-email", emailfield.value, 30);
    if (firstnamefield != null)
      setCookie("form-firstname", firstnamefield.value, 30);
    if (surnamefield != null)
      setCookie("form-surname", surnamefield.value, 30);
    location.replace(url);
  } //end setCookiesAndRedirect

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  } //end setCookies

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
  return "";
} </script>
```

```html
<p>First Name (required)<br />
   [text* Firstname id:formfirstname] </p>

<p>Last Name (required)<br />
   [text* LastName id:formsurname] </p>

<p>Your Email (required)<br />
    [email* your-email id:formemail] </p>

<p>[submit "Download Now"]</p>
```

Some links that helped me:
[cookies in all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892513/how-to-set-javascript-cookie-in-all-the-pages-globally)

[Cookies in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To Redirect properly contact form 7 please add this code.

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"
```

Remember start double commas(") -> single commas(') -> double commas(") otherwise there will be error

Comment: I've already got that working in the 1st on_sent_ok code snippet. I need to know how to set cookies as well as redirecting.

Comment: Hey JakePlatford with cookie actually what do you mean are you want to some value at redirect page or whatever.

Comment: I need the on_sent_ok to do two things: First - set a cookie, with a value of a form field and THEN second - redirect to another page

Comment: 2 thing mean redirect and save some value in cookie. if right then i have one suggeestion with redirection you take value in string and where you have redirect you form there you can save you value in cookie.

EG. on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http://www.redirectedpage.com?id=yes');"

and on next page you can save this value in cookie. it definity work

Comment: Thanks! Got it working like that which was a big help - now working on improving though, will post here when I'm finished.