# Session and Cookies in Javascript are not Stored (not Working)

Tags: javascript

I'm learning sessions and cookies in JavaScript. I have a form that takes some data and store it in session and cookies variables to be displayed in another page (second page) as follows:

```
<html> 
<body> 
<form action="second.html" onsubmit="return myFunction();"> 
Enter a session variable: <input id="sess" type="text" />
</br> 
Enter a coockie variable: <input id="cookiess" type="text" /> 

</br> 
<input type="submit" />
</form> 

<script> 
function myFunction() {
document.cookie = "username="+document.getElementById("cookiess").value + "; expires=Fri, 14 Oct 2016 12:00:00 UTC";
sessionStorage["myKey"] = document.getElementById("sess").value;

return true;
} 

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

and this is the second.html page:

```
<html> 
<body> 

<script> 

alert(sessionStorage["myKey"] + document.cookie); 
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

However, when I display the session and cookie variables in the alert function, it display empty variables. Why my session and cookies variables don't work?

Comment: Do you host both files on web server and do you refresh the second one?

Comment: No, do you mean that is the reason?

Comment: If you're just running this from a `file://` protocol, it won't work

Comment: Cookies are part of HTTP protocol. When you open a local file - it's not HTTP (it's a file:// pseudo-protocol)

Comment: You must set your cookie globally. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892513/how-to-set-javascript-cookie-in-all-the-pages-globally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi if you want to check how session storage works you can see the below code...
its for a single page.

if 2 pages are there If you're just running this from a file:// protocol, it won't work

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
            sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount)+1;
           sessionStorage["myKey"] = sessionStorage.clickcount;
        } else {
            sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session."+sessionStorage["myKey"];
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter is reset.</p>
</body>
</html>
```